# Azure functions .net 5 UseSqlServer configuration

Tags: .net, azure, entity-framework, azure-functions, .net-5

I'm trying to deploy an azure function with .net 5, "dotnet-isolated", and I can't get working sql server on it. This is my configuration startup

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
#if DEBUG
    Debugger.Launch();
#endif
    var host = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(c =>
        {
            c.AddCommandLine(args);
        })
        .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(
            (c, b) =>
            {
                b.UseFunctionExecutionMiddleware();
            })
        .ConfigureServices(
            (context, services) =>
            {
                services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
                    options =>
                        options.UseSqlServer(
                            context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
                        )
                );
            })
        .Build();
    await host.RunAsync();
}
```

Seems like the

```cs
options.UseSqlServer(context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
```

Does not recognize Azure Configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes in the ConfigureAppConfiguration. Has to be:

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration(c =>
                {
                    c.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                    c.AddCommandLine(args);
                })
```

So, the final Main is:

```
 static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
#if DEBUG
            Debugger.Launch();
#endif
            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration(c =>
                {
                    c.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                    c.AddCommandLine(args);
                })
                .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults((c, b) =>
                {
                    b.UseFunctionExecutionMiddleware();
                })
                .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                                        {
                                            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                                                options.UseSqlServer(context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
                                        })
                .Build();
            
            await host.RunAsync();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

It appears that azure is not connecting with your build either because you have it configured precariously or because of an over abundance of sql data you want it to work on so fast. My guess is the second.